# C# + TcpListener

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, tcp

Добрый день.

Я написал вин.сервис, который с помощью класса TcpListener слушает 25 порт, перехватывает почту и шлет смски.
**Ситуация следующая:** после того как мы приняли одно сообщение, следующие уже не перехватываются. Может я неправильно клиентскую сессию закрываю?

> "OnStart":

```
     Thread listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.Listen));
     listen.Start();
```

> Мой класс SmtpHelper:

```
SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
SMTP_Listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
                        clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();
                        _sessionId = clientSocket.GetHashCode().ToString();
                       _email.sessionId = Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId);

                        StartProcessing();
    }
```

> Далее, StartProcessing() :

```
 m_ConnectedIp = ParseIP_from_EndPoint(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                m_ConnectedHostName = GetHostName(m_ConnectedIp);

                l.WriteEvent(String.Format("Клиент {0}: m_ConnectedIp = {1}, m_ConnectedHostName = {2}", _sessionId, m_ConnectedIp,
                    m_ConnectedHostName));

                _email.ip = m_ConnectedIp;
                _email.port = 25;

                if (clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    l.WriteEvent(">>>Socket connected");
                }
                else
                {
                    l.WriteEvent("<<<Socket NOT connected");
                }

                SendData("220 " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + " Service ready\r\n");

                //РАБОТА С ВХОДНЫМИ ДАННЫМИ
                while (true)
                {
                    //если есть данные, то считаем их
                    if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
                    {
                        string lastCmd = ReadLine();
                        l.WriteEvent("lastCmd: " + lastCmd);

                        //break; // добавил

                        //парсим команду
                        ProceedCommand(lastCmd);
                    }
                }
```

**Может объект какой закрыть надо? получается что после того как первое сообщение приняли, другие не ловятся.**

**Спасибо!**

Comment: А отладчик что говорит?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вопрос в том - правильно ли реализовал механизм подключения к СМТП клиента?  В общих чертах. Получается, что мі приняли одн осообщение, а следующие уже ен принимаются

Comment: Вот и посмотрите отладчиком, где ваша программа застрявает после приема первого сообщения

Answer (score 1):

У вас немного нарушена логика работы. Вы делаете все в одном потоке и если к  вам подключится сразу два клиента, то неизвестно как программа себя поведет. Я бы сделал это так:

```
public class YourMainProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //... основная программа 
        new Server(25);
        //... основная программа 
    }
}

public class StartProcessing
{
    public StartProcessing(System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient Client)
    {
        /* работа с подключением. Например:
        l.WriteEvent(String.Format("Мы подключили клиента"));
        ......      
        l.WriteEvent(String.Format("Мы отключили клиента"));
        Client.Close();
        */
    }
}
public class Server
{
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener Listener;
    public Server(int Port)
    {
        Listener = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, Port);
        Listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(ClientThread), Listener.AcceptTcpClient());
        }
    }
    public static void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)
    {
        new StartProcessing((System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient)StateInfo);
    }
}
```

Получается что при подключении клиента на 25 порт, он автоматически принимается и добавляется в пул потоков (по умолчанию размер пула вроде 1023 потока). И далее, в отдельном потоке вы работаете с этим клиентом. Если в это время подключится еще один клиент, то для него создастся еще один независимый  поток.

Comment: У вас поле 'Listener` - статическое, а инициализируется в конструкторе экземпляра. Не стоит так делать.

Comment: Да) Я его сначала в главном классе прописал, а потом перенес и не исправил. Изменил.